# i get no results using LIKE in mysql when names contain CAPS characters or not

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

Example

**Names in database:**

-Sopa de pescado

-Sopa de tomate

**if i search for:**

*"Sopa"* -> 2 results

*"pescado"* -> 1 result

*"sopa"* -> 0 results ***:(***

how can i fix?

Comment: You need to show us the query you're using and ideally give us a clue of the main table schema(s). Also what's the collation on the table in question?

Comment: Hi Toni, can you include the query that you're using in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert all your search queries to lowercase and then use a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE LOWER(Column_Name) LIKE '%pescado%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LOWER() function in WHERE part of your query. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) for function details.

Also, you may use COLLATION operator. In this case query will look in the following way:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    col_name COLLATE latin1_general_ci LIKE '%sopa%';
```

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-sensitivity.html) for details.